# DynamoDb begins_with Swift 5 issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, swift5

I've been trying to get a list of visits back from Dynamodb using the begins_with option but just don't seem to be able to understand why it can't find results when running in Xcode / swift 5.

I can run the query in nodal workbench and on AWS Console. I have the same code working for simple query.

getUser() function is working

```
   func getUser() {

       // 1) Configure the query
       let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
        queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#UserID = :UserID AND #UserDataType = :UserDataType"
       queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = [
           "#UserID": "UserID",
           "#UserDataType": "UserDataType"
       ]
       queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
           ":UserID" : "1001",
           ":UserDataType" : "User"
       ]
       // 2) Make the query
       let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
       dynamoDbObjectMapper.query(HiViz.self, expression: queryExpression) { (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
           if error != nil {
               print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
           }
           if output != nil {
               for books in output!.items {
                   let booksItem = books as? HiViz
                print("\(booksItem!.Visitorid!)")
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

queryHiVizTable contains the begins_with and I can't see how to solve the issue of returning no results.

```
   func queryHiVizTable() {

       // 1) Configure the query
       let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#UserID = :UserID AND begins_with(#UserDataType, :UserDataType)"

        queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = [
           "#UserID": "UserID",
           "#UserDataType": "UserDataType"
       ]

       queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
           ":UserID" : "1001",
           ":UserDataType" : "V)"
       ]

       // 2) Make the query
       let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
       dynamoDbObjectMapper.query(HiViz.self, expression: queryExpression) { (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
        print(queryExpression)
        if error != nil {
               print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
           }
           if output != nil {
                for books in output!.items {
                                 let booksItem = books as? HiViz
                    print("\(booksItem!.Visitorid!)")
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

New to aws so appreciate the help.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

(FYI Swift 5 Xcode 11.5)

It turns out that after all of the testing I had done yesterday before posting this question this morning that I was very close to getting the code right.

in the code below I had a typo with a ) in the userdatatype which was breaking the begins_with. it should have only been V not v)

```
queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
           ":UserID" : "1001",
           ":UserDataType" : "V)"
       ]
```

the data for 1001 then came back with the different error

unrecognized selector sent to instance

this was due to the data in the DB for one row being json.

when I tested with the different user id it is working as expected.

If you use my working code below as an example while following the guide on AWS in the link you should get the begins_with to work.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-nosql-integrate-an-existing-table.html

```
 func queryHiVizTable() {

           // 1) Configure the query
           let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#UserID = :UserID AND begins_with(#UserDataType, :UserDataType)"
            queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = [
               "#UserID": "UserID",
               "#UserDataType": "UserDataType"
           ]
           queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
               ":UserID" : "1001",
               ":UserDataType" : "V"
           ]
           // 2) Make the query
           let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
           dynamoDbObjectMapper.query(HiViz.self, expression: queryExpression) { (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
            print(queryExpression)
            if error != nil {
                   print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
               }
               if output != nil {
                    for books in output!.items {
                                     let booksItem = books as? HiViz
                        print("---utututut---\(booksItem!.VisitorID!)")
                   }
               }
           }
        }
```